# Dynamic forms with Treestore

Tags: extjs, dynamic, tree, widget, alias

I trying to create dynamic forms (ultimately using AJAX proxy to pass the JSON from the server to ExtJS to make the form definition) using ExtJS 6.2.1 and the admin-dashboard template.

In my Application.js, in the `launch` function, I added a simple form with no controls:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Testing 1, 2, 3...',
            alias: 'widget.test-form',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            width: 350,

            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            }

        });
```

I do not wish to render this anywhere, but instead, make it accessible to my Treestore menu, as:

```
{
    text: 'Dynamic Test',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-check',
    viewType: 'test-form',
    leaf: true
}
```

Everything compiles great when I do a build, but then when I try to access the form from my menu, I get a 404 error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (test-form.js, line 0)
Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: widget.test-form
```

How can I get the Treestore to see my form created on launch? I also tried an `xtype` instead of an alias with a widget, but got basically the same error. More generally, how do I make the `form` variable created on `launch` available to the app so that I can access it as desired?

** EDIT **

I also tried adding in a form panel definition to my app's `launch` function:

```
Ext.define('Admin.form.TestDyno', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            alias: 'widget.test-form',

            title: 'Testing 1, 2, 3...',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            width: 350,

            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            }

         });
```

but, when I run the app, I get an error that:

```
log — Util.js:881[E] [Loader] The following classes failed to load:
log — Util.js:881[E] [Loader] Admin.form.TestDyno from classic/src/Application.js
```

Do I have to make the definition of my form in a file and then just initialize the components on app launch? I could certainly do that, but it would be nice to be able to do the form definition in the `launch`. I am thinking that something like this [launch-function-(Application)-and-set-parameters-on-the-component](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299631-Ajax-request-on-the-launch-function-(Application)-and-set-parameters-on-the-component) is more of how to implement what I need.

Answer (score 1):

For the widget type to be recognized, you don't create a new form instance.

You have to define a new derived class using `Ext.define`.

Comment: I tried that in my application `launch,` but it did not work. I will post details later.

Comment: I'm going to take an alternate approach to this problem. Instead of generating the form components dynamically, I'm going to script out the generation of the ExtJS files for the forms. The issue is that we have databased the structure of several complicated forms as adjacency lists for use in revision control and ease of creation on the fly. I should be able to take the this and serialize it to make the files. There will be some manual editing involved, but it is a much easier first step in the process. Thus, while your answer did not provide a solution, it at least got me to think.